# Verificar se CheckBox está marcada

Tags: python, tkinter

No código abaixo eu tenho uma CheckBox com nome de **cb**.

Eu queria saber quando ela estivesse selecionada/marcada para que assim o meu programa realize outra conta em vez de somar.

Como faço para detectar que a CheckBox está selecionada?

**Código:**

```
<code> 
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def calc(arg):
    if(str(ed.get()).isnumeric() and str(ed2.get()).isnumeric()):
        a = int(ed.get())
        b = int(ed2.get())
        soma = a+b
        lb1["text"] = "Soma entre os valores {}".format(soma)
        lb1["bg"] = "blue"
    else:
        lb1["text"] = "[~~ERRO~~] DIGITE APENAS NÚMEROS"
        lb1["bg"] = "red"

j = Tk()
#CHECKBOXES
cb =  Checkbutton(j)
cb.grid (row=3, column = 5)
## INPUTS 
ed = Entry(j)  #Input
ed.place(x=360, y=205)  #Input
ed2 = Entry(j)
ed2.place(x=360, y=225)

# LABELS
lbd1 = Label(j, text="Digite o 1º Número: ")
lbd2 = Label(j, text="Digite o 2º Número: ")

lbd1.place(x=200, y=200)
lbd2.place(x=200, y=220)

# BOTOES
bt1 = Button(j, width=20, height=1, bg="white", text="Ok")
bt1.place(x= 300, y= 260)
bt1["command"] = partial(calc, bt1)

#RESULTADO LABEL
lb1 = Label(j, width = 40, bg="green", text="Resultado") 
lb1.place(x=200, y=300)

# CONFIG GERAL
j.geometry("800x600+200+200")
j.mainloop()
</code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que fazer algumas alterações no código

Antes de tudo é preciso declarar uma variável que irá armazenar a mudança de statut, no caso do `checkbox ele só terá dois estados`0`ou`1`

```
checkButtonSub = IntVar()
```

Na declaração do `CheckButton` você precisa dizer que ele vai receber um parâmetro do tipo `variable` e declarar a variável `checkButtonSub`.

```
cb =  Checkbutton(j, text='subtração', variable=checkButtonSub)
```

finalmente na função `calc` verifica se `checkbutton` mudou de status

```
        if checkButtonSub.get()==1:
            resultado = a-b
        else:
            resultado = a+b
```

> Obs: mudei o nome da variável `soma` por `resultado`

Comment: Deu certo sim, eu havia pesquisado mais um pouco e encontrei essa mesma solução